# What is the relation between potential energy & electric field?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential, potential-energy

What is the relation between potential energy & electric field?

Comment: What research have you done prior to posting this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with every conservative force, the relationship between force $\vec{F}$ and potential $\phi$ is
\begin{align}
\vec{F}(\vec{r})=- \text{grad}\,  \phi(\vec{r}) \, .
\end{align}
The electric field is defined in a way, that a force $\vec{F}$ on the charge $q$ is done by an eletric field $\vec{E}$, meaning
\begin{align}
\vec{F}(\vec{r})=q\cdot\vec{E}(\vec{r}) \, .
\end{align}
The measurable qunatity of voltage $U$ is merely the potential difference between two locations: 
\begin{align}
U = \phi(\vec{r_1})- \phi(\vec{r_2}) \, .
\end{align}
From these equations you can see that the potential can always be rescaled by a constant offset as in $\phi'= \phi+\phi_0$, since
\begin{align}
\vec{F}'(\vec{r})&=- \text{grad}\,  (\phi(\vec{r})+\phi_0) = - \text{grad}\,  \phi(\vec{r}) = \vec{F}(\vec{r}) \, . \\
U' &= (\phi(\vec{r_1}) -\phi_0)- (\phi(\vec{r_2})-\phi_0) = \phi(\vec{r_1})- \phi(\vec{r_2}) = U \, .
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

A charged particle will have potential energy in an electric feild. 
There will be a force on the charged particle $F=Eq$ where E is the electric field.

The voltage between two points is the change in potential energy of a coulomb of charge moving between them.

For parallel charged plates voltage is equal to the field times the distance.
$V=Ed$

Answer (score 0):

As you might know work is defined as
$$W = \int \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}$$
From there you can easily derive the work done by an electric force (let us say produced by a static charge $Q$ for this example) while psuhing a charge $q$ to infinity:
$$W = \int_r^\infty \left( k_e \frac{Qq}{r'^2}\right)\hat{r}'\cdot d\mathbf{r'} = k_e\frac{Q q}{r}$$
One could say in analogy to the gravitational case that this potential is due to a field, recall from simple problems in kinematics, the term $mgy$ for gravitational potential energy, if you think of $m$ as the gravitational charge then $gy$ is some potential per unit charge that tells you how energy is gained and lost. Coming back to our case we can identify (keeping the reference at infinity)
$$V(r) = k_e\frac{Q}{r}$$
as the electric potential. Then one could ask oneself if there is such a notion of force per unit charge and that turns out to be exactly the electric field $E$, which you can compute from the potential through $F =  -q\nabla V(r) = q E$ in this simple case:
$$\vec{E} = k_e \frac{Q}{r^2}\hat{r}$$

This is the result of the electrical force being irrotational or conservative so that one can find a potential for it. So both the field and the potential encode the same information, roughly speaking. The advantage of working with a potential is that it is a scalar quantity rather than a vectorial one. I hope the simple example of point charges lets you understand the difference. Generalizing the charge distribution or going to a dynamical case doesn't change these basic relations.